# Bluetooth automatically enables on Lenovo T440s

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, lenovo

I want to disable Bluetooth on my Lenovo T440s, which is running 12.04 LTS. I can do it manually, but on every startup it enables the Bluetooth again. Is there a way to ensure that a simple startup wont automatically enable Bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most systems adding `rfkill block bluetooth` before `exit 0` in
`/etc/rc.local` file works.

Answer (score 2):

This also worked for my Thinkpad t430s, but not for my Lenovo x60.  In case anyone else with an uncooperative Lenovo stumbles upon this thread, try disabling bluetooth on boot, rather than killing the process.  Similar procedure:

add `echo disable > /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth` before `exit 0` in /etc/rc.local.

If that doesn't do the trick, there are a few other methods here:

http://linuxg.net/how-to-disable-bluetooth-at-startup-5-practical-methods/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have had many problems with Ubuntu on my Thinkpad T440s, here is another one; http://askubuntu.com/questions/409378/changing-brightness-at-startup/410576?noredirect=1#comment528820_410576. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @BillyJean - I'm not sure it's a solution, but I think I can point you in the right direction.  I'll reply on that thread.